# Android 2.3 Resetting app preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to reset an installed app shared preferences from android settings, without loosing the rest of the app data stored in sqlite. Just found this.-

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/29473/ok-android-jelly-bean-reset-app-preferences/

but sadly it seems there's no direct option in `Android 2.3`.

Anyone knows a workaround for clearing app preferences for `Android 2.3`?

**EDIT**

I don't have access to the devices where the app is currently installed, no chance for rooting, nor can update the app code. I'm looking for a way to clear preferences from android menu.

**EDIT 2**

Just found the option `Clear defaults` inside manage apps settings, but it seems disabled for all my apps with message `No defaults set.`; aren't these defaults the ones stored in `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 3):

you can just loop through all your `SharedPreferences` and look for the keys you want to reset

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Map<String,?> prefs = pref.getAll();
for(Map.Entry<String,?> prefToReset : prefs.entrySet()){
    edit.remove(prefToReset.getKey()).commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tyczj. Can't update the app code, sorry for the misunderstanding, I'm looking for a way to do it through android settings.

Answer (score 2):

You could connect your phone to the PC, delete your preferences file from data/data/com.****.***/. In order to do that, you need root.

Comment: Thanks @user1356158. Actually the scenario is a bit more complex, the app is installed on client devices, and don't have access to them, nor there's a chance for rooting :(